# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error even though I have the appropriate CORS middleware in place

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I keep getting the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error even though I have the following middleware in my express server (which is placed before all other middleware):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cors = require("cors");

const workoutRoutes = require("./routes/workoutRoutes");
const exerciseRoutes = require("./routes/exerciseRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const checkAuth = require("./middleware/check-auth");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  next();
});

app.use("/users", userRoutes);

app.use(checkAuth);

app.use("/workouts", workoutRoutes);
app.use("/exercises", exerciseRoutes);

app.listen(PORT);
```

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the solutions have worked for me, including using the cors npm package.

This is the alternative middleware that I tried using the cors module, which produces the same error:

```
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors({ origin: null }));
```

Any advice into why I could still be getting this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve]. If I were to speculate, I'd guess you put that code after the route which you want to access cross-origin so it doesn't get run for that route. (And don't brew your own, the `cors` module is simpler)

Comment: Hi, thanks your advice. I tried using the core module, but the same error occurs. Also, the request is for an endpoint in the '/workouts' route, so shouldn't the cors middleware be run first since it is located above it?

Comment: I think the error comes with the `true`, instead of `'true'`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, I was making the requests without a valid token, causing the following checkAuth middleware to respond with 'No valid token'.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!token) {
      res.send("No valid token");
    }
    
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
};
```

What I still don't understand is why this response did not have the appropriate headers attached if the checkAuth middleware is run after the cors middleware. Anyway, thank you all for your help.